# Icing doesn't stick to the donut in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

I am following a tutorial from Blender Guru. But at the end you of the video, the icing had to stick to the donut. But with my icing the whole thing goes into the donut! I have tried the snapping option and change it to face mode. But the icing was more sticking on to the top. And I wanted the icing to stick more in the center of the donut. Can someone help me? This is the link of the video: https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA

Here is a picture of the problem
[image: Problem in edit mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull out the icing with the *Elastic Deform* brush or *Grab* brush in *Sculp* mode. From the same angle as on the screenshot, drag the icing mesh with the mouse to the diagonal top left.

Or you can do the same in *Edit* mode but you have to select the hidden part of the icing first. Keep *Proportional Editing* on, and turn *Snapping* off.
Toggle to *Local View* (<kbd>Numpad</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>), select the verts that you want to move, toggle view back, and drag them out.

(With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you can switch between all modes.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've seen that grabbing a vertex and using the scroll wheel helped a lot! And I've made it a bit better with your method. So my problem is now solved! Thank you for helping me!